# Why does the quantum-computing tag redirect to quantum-computer instead of the opposite direction?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I find this a confusing way to lay out our tag space. Lots of questions (say, [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372259) as a recent example) are about quantum *computing* as a field, or about some specific aspect of a given quantum *computation*, without necessarily being about the specific hypothetical objects we call quantum computers.

Generally, tags on this site tend to carry the name of the *field* of inquiry, not its central object of study: we say [fluid-dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-dynamics), not [fluids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluids); [kinematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinematics), not [movement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movement), and so on.

Shouldn't the main tag be [quantum-computing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing)?

Comment: It's a secret plot by me and my sock-puppet accounts, but I won't explain it like so many would-be great villains before me who prematurely spilled their guts to 007.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the time being for pragmatic reasons. Phys.SE used to have a [quantum-computing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing) and a [quantum-computation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computation) tag, which were often [misused](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10279423#10279423) by some users whenever they had to compute something in quantum mechanics. This practice stopped once they were redirected to the [quantum-computer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computer) tag.

Comment: Hmmmmm, yeah, that's an interesting point; I guess if that does stop that kind of behaviour then the minor weirdness is worth it. When did the change take place? Was there some specific (chat, maybe?) conversation that led to it, that might be good to link to from here?

Comment: It was discussed in the hbar chat room around [Jul 10th, 2013](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10279423#10279423).

Comment: OK, so ancient history, then. Thanks for filling in slow learners like me ;-).